# Numbers Divisible by All Primes Less or Equal to Itself

Tags: prime-numbers

Just to preface, I haven't put too much thought into the following lemma/conjecture: The only number divisible by all primes less or equal to itself is two.

Unless I am overlooking something, this conjecture is not as easy to prove rigorously as one might think. So far, I **believe** that one way to disprove this claim, to break the "only" part, is to show that the difference in consecutive prime numbers is bounded by a constant. In other words, if $p_i$ denotes the $i$th prime number, and if $$max(p_i - p_{i - 1}) = \Omega(1),$$ we can deduce that there must be some finitely large number that is divisible by all primes less than or equal to itself.

However, I am unable to grasp the intuition or reasoning behind this. To summarize, I wish to know if the conjecture stated earlier has been proven or disproven before, and if not, whether my approach for disproving it is accurate.

Comment: 6 is divisible by all primes less than or equal to 6, so 2 isn't the only possibilty.

Comment: @MilesB:  $6$ is not divisible by $5$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner - I feel stupid!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from Bertrand's postulate.

Answer (score 3):

If $n>2$, let $p$ be a prime that divides $n-1$.  By assumption, $p|n$, so $p|n-(n-1)=1$, contradiction.